# Start a list from a certain number

Tags: html, css, html-lists

What's the best way to get a `ol` to start from 'x'?

The `start` tag is deprecated and everything I have found on Google has used the `:before` pseudo class which doesn't work in IE6 or 7. Didn't have much luck when searching stack either.

Only thing I can think of is manually go through and number the lists myself and style accordingly?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Well, for starters... an "ul" is an unordered list.  Perhaps, you want "ol".

Comment: OK, so "start" is depricated. So what?  It still works on IE6 & 7. If that is your target browser, just use it.

Comment: If there is no alternative I will have to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the [`start` attribute in HTML 4 is indeed deprecated](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html#h-10.2), looking at the [HTML 5 docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/semantics.html#the-ol-element), I see:

> The `start`  attribute, if present, must be a valid integer giving the ordinal value of the first list item.
>
> If the `start` attribute is present, user agents must parse it as an integer, in order to determine the attribute's value. The default value, used if the attribute is missing or if the value cannot be converted to a number according to the referenced algorithm, is 1 if the element has no `reversed` attribute, and is the number of child `li` elements otherwise.
>
> The first item in the list has the ordinal value given by the `ol` element's start attribute, unless that `li` element has a value attribute with a value that can be successfully parsed, in which case it has the ordinal value given by that value attribute.

which tells me I am safe using `start` with `ol` and `value` with `li` elements.

Answer (score 0):

With ordered lists `ol`, you could use the various `counter` CSS instructions: [Examples here](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/counter.html). But, they also won't work with IE6 and 7. I don't think there is a non-Javascript way to make this work in them.