# Way to start list from a certain number within xhtml doctypes

Tags: html, xhtml, doctype

Now according to this post: [Start a list from a certain number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496158/start-a-list-from-a-certain-number) this has been deprecated, but it has been bought back in HTML5.

I'm not using HTML5, I'm using the transitional XHTML doctype.

So I'm wondering what I can use?

If I just go ahead and use..

```
<ol start=5>
```

Will it still work? I know I can just test it, but also want to make sure that all browsers will still show it as I intend?

**Edit:** I need something that is 100% reliable, not a CSS solution that has limited support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The XHTML transitional DTD [allows](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/dtds.html#a_dtd_XHTML-1.0-Transitional) `<ol>` (ordered list)  with a `start` attribute. Maybe you were using the wrong element? (`<ul>` instead of `<ol>`).

If the browser follows the XHTML1.0 Transitional rules it should render the list correctly.

Comment: Thanks. I thought it remained deprecated within XHTML as well seeing as everything I stumbled across said it was deprecated for HTML 4 and to use the CSS method.

Answer (score 1):

The 'start' attribute is fine for XHTML Transitional, but has no effect on unordered lists (ul, for obvious reasons). Just use:

```
<ol start="5">
  <li>My first list item</li>
  <li>My second list item</li>
  <li>etc.</li>
</ol>
```

Some may argue that you should be separating the numbering from the markup as it's presentaitonal and use CSS counters instead. Funny how it's valid again in HTML5 though, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using an unordered list there. Try this:

```
<ol start="5">
    <li>This is number 5</li>
    <li>This is number 6</li>
    <li>This is number 7</li>
    <li>This is number 8</li>
</ol>
```

Example.

Comment: Putting `ul` in the example was a mistake, fixed it ;)

Answer (score -1):

See that: http://norman.walsh.name/2011/08/12/styleThis